# Questions that are on-topic on several SE sites

Tags: discussion

It is not so uncommon that some questions asked on Biology.SE are on-topic but would be, IMO, an even better fit on Skeptics.SE, Health.SE or CognitiveSciences.SE. Migrating such post will probably allow the OP to get a better, more complete answer.

Should I flag such questions for migration or should they be accepted on Biology.SE as they are on-topic here too?

Answer (score 2):

If they are on-topic and can be answered here, I don't see a reason to migrate them. If they fit much better into another stackexchange, then flag it for migration.